# How to add action buttons like edit and delete to dynamic gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added a GridView which is generated dynamically. I am fetching rows from DB and loading it into DataTable. I want to add edit and delete Button to this DataTable and bind it to GridView so that i can edit and delete content of GridView. The GridView is generated more than one time and is called in loop as it is need to generate timesheet for weeks. Here is source code for binding data and GridView generation:

```
protected void BindData(string str)
{
    string[] startdate = getdate(str);
    int firstdate = Convert.ToInt32(startdate[1]);
    int lastdate = firstdate + 7;
    string enddate = startdate[0]+"/"+Convert.ToString(lastdate)+"/"+startdate[2];
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT (varchar(25), Cale_WeekDate,106) AS 'Date',Cale_DayName AS 'Day',Cale_Task8 AS '08:00 AM',Cale_Task9 AS '09:00 AM',Cale_Task10 AS '10:00 AM',Cale_Task11 AS '11:00 AM',Cale_Task12 AS '12:00 PM',Cale_Task13 AS '1:00 PM' FROM Calendar WHERE Cale_WeekDate BETWEEN '"+str+"' AND '"+enddate+"'", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);               
    GridView gvTimeSheet = new GridView();
    //gvTimeSheet.ID = "gvTimeSheet" + gridcount;
    gvTimeSheet.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
        boundfield.DataField = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        boundfield.HeaderText = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        gvTimeSheet.Columns.Add(boundfield);
    }
    gvTimeSheet.DataSource = dt;
    gvTimeSheet.DataBind();
    gvTimeSheet.Width = 600;
    gvTimeSheet.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "header";
    gvTimeSheet.RowStyle.CssClass = "rowstyle";

    Panel1.Controls.Add(gvTimeSheet);
    HtmlGenericControl linebreak = new HtmlGenericControl("br");            
    Panel1.Controls.Add(linebreak);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net we can do this with:

```
    <asp:GridView>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" CommandArgument='btnTest' runat="server" Text="Test et" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnVerify" CommandArgument='btnVerify' runat="server" Text="Verify" OnClick="btnVerify_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In code side:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Also you can add buttons as column in runtime.

Comment: But i want dynamically as gridview is generating dynamically. Therefore i need to add buttons in in runtime itself. gridview can be generated more than one time so need all buttons dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Take the maximum number of columns, suppose you have 3 databound columns(i=3), add template columns at position(i+1=4) for edit and next template column for delete at position (i+1=5).